# How to calculate the Exif metadata YCbCrPositioning from an image?

Tags: jpg, exif

I'm checking how to calculate that value from a JPEG file and I'm pretty confused:

YCbCrPositioning should be defined as shown in this page: https://freeimage.sourceforge.io/fnet/html/4A015DE9.htm

This page is already a bit unclear, but I think what it means is that if Y=4, Cb=2 and Cr=2 then YCbCrPositioning should be set to 2, in all other cases to 1.

That Y:Cb:Cr seems to refer to this thing: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YCbCr

There it says how each of these values would be calculate, for example Y, would be calculated as shown here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luma_(video), and Cb and Cr as shown here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chrominance.

But at this point I'm pretty lost, how can you get the values needed to calculate Y, Cb and Cr from a JPEG image?

Comment: This question might confuse. 4:2:2 and 4:2:0 are chroma subsampling schemes. For 4:2:2, two horizontal consecutive luma values (Y) share one chroma sample (Cb+Cr). For 4:2:0, a block of 2x2 luma samples (Y) shares one chroma sample (Cb+Cr). 4:2:2 and 4:2:0 are just "names" and "Y:Cb:Cr" or "Y=4,Cb=2,Cr=2" doesn't make any sense. The question is, if the chroma samples (Cb+Cr) are sampled in in the middle between the luma samples: "YCbCrPositioning=1 (centered)", or at the position of the (top-)left luma sample: "YCbCrPositioning=2 (co-cited)". That info can't be "calculated" but must be known.

Answer (score 1):

You can read the Y, Cb, and Cr values with any EXIF reader.  [EXIF Tools](https://sourceforge.net/projects/exiftool/) is a nice choice.
You can also [read the EXIF values with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764932/in-python-how-do-i-read-the-exif-data-for-an-image) if you like.
Here is a screen shot from EXIF Tool.

[image]